# Do you still get War Assets that count on the ending after... (spoilers)

Tags: mass-effect-3

... attacking the base of the Illusive Man?

Right now I am at 5015 Military Strength and did not get my EMS up yet. Considering that I need 5k (did not destroy the Reaper Base in ME2) to get the best Ending, I would have to play for 100% Readieness which I am not really up to. Can I still get it to like 6000 at this point?

I did collect a fair share of stuff from Planets etc, but not everything. However, those assets tend to be like 25 points only, so I don't think it would make such a big difference. I am also pretty much out of Quests..

[image: War Assets]
[image: Journal]

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but if you're playing with the Extended Cut DLC (free until April 12, 2014), the EMS required for best ending is 3100. Otherwise it's 4000, not 5000.

Comment: @Kareen Are you sure about that? There are so many different answers on the extranet. I do have the DLC installed.

Comment: That is what the Mass Effect wiki says on its [Extended Cut DLC page](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3:_Extended_Cut), in the Updates and Fixes section, which sources a [tweet from Michael Gamble](https://twitter.com/GambleMike/status/217335034787545088), a producer on the ME franchise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No

There are no further war assets after you complete Priority: Cerberus Headquarters.

Note that you've received either the Reaper Heart (100) or the Reaper Brain (110) as War Assets augmenting the Crucible by completing this mission - based on your decision to save the Collector base in Mass Effect 2 you will get the Reaper Brain.

If your Galactic Readiness is not at 100% you can increase your effective military strength by playing a few multiplayer missions.

Comment: Since you are an expert on ME3, can you confirm what Kareen added? That you only 3100 EMS with the Extended Cut?

Comment: @Assylum Kareen cited a link to the Mass Effect pages on wikia which states "[The required Effective Military Strength rating to achieve all possible endings is lowered from 4,000 to 3,100](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3:_Extended_Cut)" under "Fixes and Updates", at the bottom. Provided you have the Extended Cut DLC installed you only need 3100 EMS to get the best ending.

Comment: Didn't want to read the wiki, too much spoilers. Well, Game is finished now, from ME1 to 3 with all my own saves. Was a good ride. The ending was kinda disappointing though. Expected more. But I guess in this case we all expected more than Bioware could have ever delivered.